# Dealing with the over function in R: how to plot temporal trends of an "over" object?

Tags: r, function, plot, temporal

I have a dataset called `carcass`, which contains occurrences of livestock carcasses in Norway in the last 5 years (each raw corresponds to a single carcass, which has an `ID number`, along with `longitude`, `latitude` and *year*). I have also a shapefile called *regions*, a vector file over the different regions in Norway (every region has an ID number as well, specified in the column `number_reg`).

I managed to plot the map of the regions in R, and to plot the points corresponding to each carcass over the map.

```
regions<-readShapeSpatial("\\\\homer.uit.no/fma023/Desktop/Filippo Marolla/Datasets/rbd2012_siida.shp")
plot(regions)

carcass<-readShapePoints("\\\\homer.uit.no/fma023/Desktop/Filippo Marolla/Datasets/carcass_data_edit.shp")
plot(carcass, add=T, pch=20, cex=.5, col="red")
```

Then, I managed to count how many points fall within each district using the over function:

```
res<-table(over(carcass, regions)$number_reg
```

I also managed to plot the temporal trend of carcass occurrences for the entire country:

```
plot(table(carcass$YEAR), type="o", ylab="Carcass occurrences", main="Temporal trend of carcass occurrences in Norway")
```

Now I need to plot carcass occurrences over time **for every single region**, i.e. I want a graph with number of carcasses on y-axis and time (year) on x-axis for region 1, same graph for region 2, same graph for region 3, and so forth.

However, I am in trouble since the *over* function in R "(...) at the spatial location of object x retrieves the indexes or attributes from spatial object y", therefore in my *res* object I don't have the column *year* included (because *year* is in the *carcass* dataset, not in the *regions* dataset).